# Use regex to find any number with a decimal place

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
15372185 ChocolateBiscuit 1.20
13281038 AppleJuice 1.50
26419633 TomatoSoup 2.10
74283187 SpringRolls 0.90
```

Basically, i want to match any number that has a decimal place (which is the last number for each line. To find the 8 digit number at the beginning and the description i have this:

```
codes = re.findall(r'\d{8}', fread)
details = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*', fread)
```

I assume i use something similar to find all the numbers with decimal points? I just dont understand how i would do that.

Comment: Yeah, because i'm developing another version of my code. I wanted to use regex (since i'm new to it and i want to understand how to use it better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
   file = f.read()
re.findall(r'\b\d+\.\d+\b', file)
```

results:

```
['1.20', '1.50', '2.10', '0.90']
```

Search for any number of digits surrounding the decimal place, enclose in boundaries.

If you need to also capture numbers like .23, use:

```
re.findall(r'[\d+]*\.\d+', file)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `.23`.

Comment: I assume the number would be 0.23, no?

Comment: Why would it? `.23` is a perfectly valid real number.

Comment: Considering the fact that a) none of the numbers have more than 1 significant figures past the decimal point in the file and that b) the numbers in the file are written as x.y and not just .y, this does work (where x and y are numbers). For my purposes it works anyway.

Comment: I've aded a regex for the corner-case, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

'Get text to match

```
Dim fileText As String = "WhereEver.txt"
```

'Create a Match String including the acceptance of numbers like ".23"

```
Dim Reg As New Regex("(\d) (.+) (\d\.\d|\.\d)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

'Get all Matches within the String.

```
Dim regMatch As MatchCollection = Reg.Matches(fileText)
```

'Iterate through each group and get the 3rd Item, which would be the decimal number.

```
For x = 0 To regMatch.Count - 1
    DoWhatEverYouNeedToDoWithIt()
    MsgBox(regMatch.Item(x).Groups.Item(3).Value)
Next
```

Can get Item() 1 to 3 (1 being the 8 digit number, 2 being the name, and 3 being the decimal) withing the `For[...]` to return which value you want. Or the entire group to get it all. *Item 3 is used in my example code.*

All code: *(Tested & works)*

```
Dim fileText As String = "WhereEver.txt"
Dim Reg As New Regex("(\d) (.+) (\d\.\d|\.\d)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim regMatch As MatchCollection = Reg.Matches(fileText)
For x = 0 To regMatch.Count - 1
    MsgBox(regMatch.Item(x).Groups.Item(3).Value)
Next
```